# Verify the contents of an ISO without root access using python

Tags: python, linux, permissions, mount, iso

I'm creating an ISO image of a given filesystem in python by calling `subprocess.Popen('mkisofs',..)`. After this, I want to verify the ISO contents somehow.

To do this, I thought about mounting the ISO locally and then run a `diff -r` on both, the source as well as the mounted fs. Unfortunately, this needs superuser permissions for doing a `mount -o loop <iso> <fs-target>`.

Is there any cool way to do this verification in a smart way without super user permissions?

Comment: use devdump,  isoinfo,  isovfy,  isodump from the same cdrtools package